# Removing brackets from column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that has data in the below format:

```
name,type
P1,["prod_1", "prod_3"]
P2,["prod_2", "prod_3"]
P3,None
```

I am trying to convert this such that I get the below output:

```
name,type
P1,"prod_1", "prod_3"
P2,"prod_2", "prod_3"
P3,None
```

The data type of `df['type']` is object

I tried to use regular expression as below:

```
df['type'] = df['type'].replace("[", df['type'])
df['type'] = df['type'].replace("]", df['type'])
```

But this still returns the same output with the brackets before and after

Comment: use this `df['type'].str.replace('\[|\]','')`

Comment: @MohamedThasinah, tried the above, still returns the same output as input

Comment: What exactly is the output you want... a string  but without leading or trailing `[]`s, then maybe `df['type'].str.strip('[]')` but it does look like you've got what is actually a list there... (note that `pd.Series.replace` (which you're using) and 
 `pd.Series.str.replace` are *very* different things)

Comment: @scottmartin - sorry i forgot to put .str accessor. please take updated comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this,

```
df['type']=df['type'].str.replace('\[|\]','')
```

O/P:

```
  name                type
0   P1  'prod_1', 'prod_3'
1   P2  'prod_2', 'prod_3'
2   P3                None
```

Docs:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html

`str.replace` receives regex as replacement pattern, `|`used here as `or` and `\` escape character used here to differentiate from regex character

As @ Jon Clements suggests `strip` would be the best choice for this problem.

```
df['type'] = df['type'].str.strip('[]')
```

Comment: If `[]` appear anywhere apart from the start/end of the string, this will remove them as well - which probably isn't desirable... Also - making use of regex here isn't really necessary... - one can just use `.str.strip('[]')` which'll be more efficient and only concern itself with leading/trailing chars...

Comment: @JonClements - I completely agree with you, please take a look at updated answer :)

Comment: @sentence - Op mentioned dtype as object here `The data type of df['type'] is object`. Moreover keeping list dtype in pandas series is not recommended

Comment: Run your code on this DataFrame: `df = pd.DataFrame({"name":['P1','P2','P3'],
                  "type":[["prod_1", "prod_3"],["prod_2", "prod_3"], None]})` and you see. ;)

Comment: @sentence - I understood your intention, that's what I'm also trying to convey `my code will not work  for list type but OP requested this question for object dtype`

Comment: @MohamedThasinah Your code works fine for this DataFrame: `df = pd.DataFrame({"name":['P1','P2','P3'],
                  "type":["[prod_1, prod_3]","prod_2, prod_3", None]})`. I am just pointing out that the question itself is confusing because the data are not clearly provided by the OP. And the data, in fact. matter. ;)